# How to upload a .doc file using WCF service and javascript form post

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, wcf

I tried to upload a file from a jQuery form post. I used the following html along with the jQuery codes:

```
<form id="file_upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
     <input type="file" name="uploadcv" id="uploadcv" size="30" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var url = ServiceLocation + "/UploadFile";   //ServiceLocation = my service location

$("#file_upload_form").attr("action", url);

$("#file_upload_form").submit();
```

In the WCF part I used the following service method

```
public string UploadFile(Stream  inputStream)
{
        const int bufferSize = 8 * 1024 * 2;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        Stream outputStream = null;
        string newFileName = @"D:\AllTxtFiles.doc";
        outputStream = new FileInfo(newFileName).OpenWrite();

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        inputStream.Close();
        outputStream.Close();

}
```

This works, when I try to upload a `.txt` file. However, I need to upload a `.doc` file with different tables and formatting.

When I tried to do that, `AllTxtFiles.doc` contains some non-understandable texts.

I tried and searched for the whole day, but failed (probably because I am new in WCF). Can anyone please help me to do that?

Comment: are you able to upload big text file ?

Answer (score 1):

The form cannot be posted to the stream argument, only the stream itself:

```
function upload() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', 'wcf/WCFUploader.svc/Upload/');
  request.send(filePicker.files[0]);
}
```

All the details are available here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/757991/File-Upload-using-WCF-REST-API-and-JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

Here are helpful links:

[file upload to wcf using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781633/file-upload-to-wcf-using-jquery)

[Uploading a file to WCF service using HTML5 and/or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684000/uploading-a-file-to-wcf-service-using-html5-and-or-jquery)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327420/WCF-REST-Service-with-JSON

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP